# Telegram takes up a lot of space on macbook

Tags: macos, unix, monterey

There is a folder on my macbook (mac os Monterey):

```
Library/Group containers/Telegram/stable/account-.../postbox/db/db_sqlite
```

and it contains a ***4.3 GB db_sqlite file.***

There are not so many groups and chats in my telegram that they take up so much space.

Can I remove it so it doesn't take up so much space on my PC? Nowhere did I find any information about this file, whether it can be deleted or not.

Thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: sqlite is a database format. idk Telegram, but one would imagine that's your conversation history. Only delete it if you want to clear the history… & still it would probably be better to do that from within the app, not by throwing out its database.